# Unable to position <TextInput> cursor to the horizontal center of screen with React Native Dimensions

Tags: css, react-native

I am attempting to keep a View centered horizontally on the screen like such:

```
  <Animated.View style={{
     position: 'absolute',
     top: '35%',
     width: '30%',
     marginLeft: this.state.center,
  }}>

     <TextInput/>

 </Animated.View>
```

It basically keeps the `<TextInput/>` centered as the user types by decreasing the `marginLeft` value by a fixed amount on typing and increasing the `marginLeft` when deleting. When the `<TextInput/>` is empty, the blinking cursor simply remains horizontally centered in the screen.

The problem I'm having then is that when `center = Dimensions.get('window').width / 2` is applied to the `marginLeft` style property of the `<Animated.View>`, it isn't exactly at the center point of the screen. It's approximately `3.8` DPI off-center to the right.

Would anyone know what could be causing this margin of error?`Dimensions.get('window').width` returns a floating point that appears to be exact.. 
Could it maybe be the division operation that introduces a rounding error?

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't an issue with `Dimensions` after all. In this particular case, it seems that `<TextInput/>` automatically adjusts its own position to the right by an approximate value of `PixelRatio.get()` dpi. The next thing I needed to offset was the cursor width itself, which is `1`.

So to get the "center point" of the screen for the `<TextInput/>` cursor it was:

```
var windowCenterPoint = (Dimensions.get('window').width / 2) - PixelRatio.get() - 1;
```